# Cannot start MySQL

Tags: mysql, start

I used this command from shell to repair all Databases

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p --auto-repair --check --optimize --all-databases
```

and after that I restarted the server

when it came back alive again I tried to open my vBulletin forum but I recived Database error message.

and also tried to open phpMyAdmin but I received this error :

```
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I checked the services list and found that the MySQL Service is not listed, so I tried to start it from shell I receive this error :

```
Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]
```

could anyone help me in that ?

thanks in advance.

---

***update***

I found these lines in the log file

```
101101 01:36:01 mysqld started
101101 1:36:01 [Warning] Asked for 196608 thread stack, but got 126976
101101 1:36:01 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mysql/user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
101101 1:36:01 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Table './mysql/user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
101101 1:36:01 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table './mysql/user' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed
101101 01:36:01 mysqld ended
```

What should I do then ?

Comment: What about in error log?

Comment: Where Could I find it Gennady ?

Comment: sudo less /var/log/mysql.err   or    sudo less /var/log/mysql.log   or   sudo less /var/log/syslog

I have messages from mysql in the syslog file.

Answer (score 3):

This occurs when mysqld is not properly shutdown.  Basically, the pid file--a file that contains the process id of the currently running process--exists to detect whether or not the process is actively running.  When the system is out of whack--i.e., it found the pid but can't find the process, meaning the server was not stopped correctly--it requires manual intervention.

Simply `rm /var/run/mysqld.pid` and you should be fine.

Andrew

UPDATE: Based on your recent log files (and the fact that automatic repairs failed), here's a [great post on additional repair methods](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/showthread.php?44909-3-ways-to-repair-a-database&s=).  Additionally, make sure you have enough disk space on the server.

Comment: thanks Andrew, but it still not working ):

Answer (score 3):

Try starting mysqld with --skip-grant-tables so it won't try to load the (crashed) user table.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start --skip-grant-tables
```

then log into mysql

```
mysql
```

then try the repair command on the user table

```
use mysql; 
REPAIR TABLE user;
```

I'm not sure that syntax is 100% correct.

Comment: for me: /etc/init.d/mysql start --skip-grant-tables

Answer (score 1):

I think you need mysqlrepair:

```
mysqlrepair -r tablename
```

(Just realized this is the same as mysqlcheck.)

What you need is explicit repair instead of autorepair.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved :)

Thanks cstamas, Resorath, Andrew & Gennady, thanks all for your help :)

I tried this from shell, and it worked just fine:

```
service mysql stop 
mkdir /home/tmp
cd /var/lib/mysql
myisamchk --tmpdir=/home/tmp -r */*.MYI
service mysql start
```

Comment: Glad we could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on xampp, for xampp first go to `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\` and start daemon

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --datadir=C:\xampp\mysql\data\
```

Then open another terminal on same path and run `mysqlcheck` to find which tables need repair

```
mysqlcheck mysql -a
```

After that run `mysql` and repair the tables

```
mysql
use mysql; 
REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

I hope can fix it without any more issue